# how to Url rewriting for shared hosting of godaddy sub folders

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite URL of my sub folders ,

I have **mysite.php/subfolder/login/index.php**
where i want to rewrite the url into any **encrypted format** or want latest
**mysite.php/login/index.php** where i want to hide the sub folder

Hope any can help i tried with ,**htaccess** but it didn't work ..

thank in advance ....

Comment: What did you try, in what way did it not work? (Edit the question).

Comment: Please explain a little more and i tried answering your question as per my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^login\/index\.php$ /subfolder/login/index.php [L]
```

That is the max i understood from your question.

Comment: have no idea how to work just added some .htaccess code to root file n its not working

Comment: ur code works but css of the page is not working ... help  .?

Comment: Thank;s Yadav keep helping all :)